# Errors during install GNOME Desktop in ubuntu Docker container, remote control with XRDP！

Tags: gnome, docker, ubuntu-gnome, xrdp, container

I have tried the several steps and several times to build a Docker image for Ubuntu Desktop in container.

My steps are as follows:

1. Using the official Docker image of ubuntu:

```shell
docker run -tid --name xrdp -p 3389:3389 ubuntu:latest
```

2. Attach to the container:

```shell
docker attach xrdp
```

3. Update the system:

```shell
apt update
```

4. Install the GNOME Desktop environment:

```shell
apt install ubuntu-desktop -y
```

5. Install the `xrdp`

```shell
apt install xrdp -y
```

6. Set the password for `root` and start the `xrdp` service:

```shell
passwd root
service xrdp start
```

7. Connect to container using `mstsc.exe` on local machine.
8. Type in username and password (using credential of `root` user)
9. It looks like PASS the authenticate, but it disconnect immediately, **always** quit immediately.
10. I observed there are some error or warning message in the output of container:

```
xrdp-sesman[25229]: [INFO ] Socket 7: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 42214

xrdp-sesman[25229]: [INFO ] Terminal Server Users group is disabled, allowing authentication

xrdp-sesman[25229]: [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip ::ffff:221.212.116.25:1207 - socket: 11

xrdp-sesman[25229]: [INFO ] starting Xorg session...

xrdp-sesman[25229]: [INFO ] Starting session: session_pid 25239, display :10.0, width 2560, height 1600, bpp 24, client ip ::ffff:221.212.116.25:1207 - socket: 11, user name root

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] [session start] (display 10): calling auth_start_session from pid 25239

xrdp-sesman[25229]: [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed

xrdp-sesman[25239]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
xrdp-sesman[25239]: pam_systemd(xrdp-sesman:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
xrdp-sesman[25229]: [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans

xrdp-sesman[25241]: [INFO ] Starting X server on display 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log  

xrdp-sesman[25240]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10


xrdp-sesman[25240]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] Session started successfully for user root on display 10

xrdp-sesman[25244]: [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 10

xrdp-sesman[25240]: [INFO ] Starting the default window manager on display 10: /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] Session in progress on display 10, waiting until the window manager (pid 25240) exits to end the session

xrdp-chansrv[25244]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_UNIX connection received

xrdp-chansrv[25244]: [INFO ] sound_process_training: round trip time 101

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 25240, display 10) exited with non-zero exit code 255 and signal 5. This could indicate a window manager config problem

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 25240, display 10) exited quickly (1 secs). This could indicate a window manager config problem

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] Calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 25239

xrdp-sesman[25239]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session closed for user root
xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] Terminating X server (pid 25241) on display 10

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] Terminating the xrdp channel server (pid 25244) on display 10

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] X server on display 10 (pid 25241) returned exit code 0 and signal number 0

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] xrdp channel server for display 10 (pid 25244) exit code 0 and signal number 0

xrdp-sesman[25239]: [INFO ] cleanup_sockets:

xrdp-sesman[25229]: [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :10.0, session_pid 25239, ip ::ffff:221.212.116.25:1207 - socket: 11
```

Then, I search on the Internet, some people talk about inserting something into the `~/.xsession` file, but I can't find this file in the `~/` directory.

So what should I do if I want to enable the GNOME Desktop Environment for ubuntu in Docker container and get access from remote machine using XRDP?

Thank you for your time!